# Why is this instance of realloc giving me SIGABRT?

Tags: c

Here is the code in question, it's a function that reallocs a int array and adds a number to the end of it

```
int *add_to_array(int *arr, unsigned int num, int newval)
{
    if(arr != NULL){

        int *newarr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * (num+1));
            if(!newarr){
                free(arr);

            }else{
                free(newarr);
            }
            arr[num] = newval;
            return arr;
   }
   else{

    return NULL;

   }

}
```

Problem is, when I call this function once, it works fine, but if I call it a second time, the debugger gives me a SIGABRT at the line

```
int *newarr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * (num+1));
```

Here is how I'm calling the function

```
array = add_to_array(array, 5, 10);
array = add_to_array(array, 6, 100);
```

EDIT: I managed to solve this with this new code

```
int *add_to_array(int *arr, unsigned int num, int newval)
{
if(arr != NULL){

int *newarr =realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * (num+1));
if(!newarr){
    return NULL;
}else{
 newarr[num] = newval;
 return newarr;
}
}
else{

    return NULL;

}

}
```

One more question, in the event whereby realloc fails to realloc the given pointer arr, does arr becomes null in that instance or is it still valid?

Comment: So you allocate a new array (freeing the old array in the process), then free the new array, then write data to the old array which is now freed?

Comment: If the allocation fails, free the memory pointed to by the pointer to the original array, if it succeeds, free the memory space you've successfully allocated and write to it ??

Comment: `if(!newarr){
                free(arr);return NULL;

            }else{
                arr = newarr
            }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why free(arr)? It doesn't make sesne to free the old data in case of failure

Comment: @OhadEytan `array = add_to_array(array, 5, 10);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thats true, but should handled outside, perhaps by checking of the return value.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and read [about **undefined behavior**](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment of my code the old array stays valid. If you used my code mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If realloc fails you probably want to save the old array and do nothing, so:

```
        if(!newarr){
            free(arr);
```

Should be:

```
        if(!newarr){
            return NULL // Allocation fails, the old array saved. Check the return value outside the function 
        }
```

If realloc succeed, you sure don't want to free the new array, just update the last value in it, so:

```
        }else{
            free(newarr);
        }
        arr[num] = newval;
        return arr;
```

Should be:

```
        newarr[num] = newval;
        return newarr;
```

Comment: If realloc fails then the old memory should be freed manually At this point the pgm may not continue and should be aborted.

Comment: @sjsam Why free the old memory and lose the data? Maybe he want save it or do another thing

Comment: The reason why `realloc` was called is because more data needed to be added to be added to the heap for the program to give the desired result. What is the point in continuing the program if the program ran out of memory. May be abort? Or  the op may write a fallback code.

Comment: @sjsam sometimes you want to save the old data before you abort or free another memory and continue

Comment: In that case, you have already metioned how to do it. ;) So take a ^ for that.

Answer (score 2):

Not only doesn't

```
    else{
           free(newarr); 
        }
```

make sense but also it defies the purpose of

```
int *newarr = realloc(arr, sizeof(int) * (num+1));
```

If `realloc` is successful, do `arr=newarr`.

---

**Reference**

[[ realloc ]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) reference says:

> On success, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated
>   memory. The returned pointer must be deallocated with free() or
>   realloc(). The original pointer ptr is invalidated and any access to
>   it is undefined behavior (even if reallocation was in-place).
>
> On failure, returns a null pointer. The original pointer ptr remains
>   valid and may need to be deallocated with free() or realloc().

Comment: Your last sentence is bogus — the address returned by `realloc()` is not always the address passed in, even when the allocation is successful.  In other words, `realloc()` may move the data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Valid point, and `chance of moving` is the reason we used a new pointer `newarr`. Thankyou ;)

Comment: It's probably doesn't happen it reality, but you don't fix the code for the case realloc fails

Comment: @OhadEytan : `it probably doesn't happen it reality`   Probably yes ! with the luxury of virtual memory MIPS assures each pgm. But neglecting `it` is a bad practice.

Comment: Of course. Thats why it's better if you treat the `if(!newarr){...}` in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code causes undefined behavior when you try to write to original block after reallocation. If reallocation fails - you free that block manually before writing, in other case you must not touch that block because `realloc()` has returned new one and original one bay be freed internally. And SIGABRT - is an implementation-specific notification about detected heap corruption or misusing of malloc-family API. Read about [realloc()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html) carefully.